# After switching with the router in the navbar, I get a loop when I start the download process electron-dl,electron-download-manager

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

After switching with the router in the navbar, I get a loop when I start the download process.

how can i fix this i coldn't do it for 2 days i cant fix

[image: 1]

```
function downloaddosya1() {
  console.log("Files1 downloading...")
  const url = "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/100MB.zip"
  ipcRenderer.invoke("downloadmng",url);
}
// DOSYA 1
function checkdosya() {
const yereldosya = 'C:\\test\\xampp-control.exe'
const yereldosyahash ='ed4d6fdb6248bcff64e5652cd0c9d79c483bace94c1120dc3128645f00a5e5c4'
fs.exists(yereldosya, function(exists) { 
  if (exists) { 
    console.log("Dosya Var")
getChecksum(yereldosya)
.then(checksum => { apidosya(checksum) })
.catch(err => console.log(err));
const apidosya = async(checksum) => {
  if(checksum == yereldosyahash){
      checkdosyadone()
}else{
  console.log("Files 1 False")
  downloaddosya1()
}
}
}else{
    console.log("Dosya Yok")
    downloaddosya1()
  }
});
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that explains what this means: "After switching with the router in the navbar, I get a loop when I start the download process."  And can you show which console.log is showing the file progress?  What's the actual vs expected behavior?  We need clearer explanation to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="topPanel"><div id="panel"></div>
    <router-link to="Dashboard" class="topPanelItem textMenu" active-class="activeMenu">Home</router-link>
    <router-link to="Store" class="topPanelItem textMenu" active-class="activeMenu">Store</router-link>
    <div @click="checkdosya()" to="Play" id="logoBN" class="playButton">Play</div>
    <router-link to="News" class="topPanelItem textMenu" active-class="activeMenu">News</router-link>
    <div  @click="CreateAcc()" class="topPanelItem textMenu">Support</div>
    <div  @click="CreateAcc()" class="topPanelItem textMenu2">Forum</div>
    <div  @click="downloadmng()" class="topPanelItem textMenu2">Discord</div>
  </div>
```

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/800760836217765888/1085288422995922994/dsada.txt

i cant share other code i share files

```
ipcMain.handle("downloadmng",(event,url)=>{
  downloader.download({
    url: url,
    onProgress: (progress,item) => {
      event.sender.send("progress",progress);
    }
  },function(error,info){
    event.sender.send("downloadmngtrue");
    event.sender.send("info",info)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a routing problem or there is a problem with the main,renderer

this main procress

```
    ipcMain.handle("downloadmng",(event,url)=>{
  downloader.download({
    url: url,
    onProgress: (progress,item) => {
      event.sender.send("progress",progress);
    }
```

this navbar

```
    <div class="topPanel"><div id="panel"></div>
    <router-link to="Dashboard" class="topPanelItem textMenu" active-class="activeMenu">Home</router-link>
    <router-link to="Store" class="topPanelItem textMenu" active-class="activeMenu">Store</router-link>
    <div @click="checkdosya()" to="Play" id="logoBN" class="playButton">Play</div>
    <router-link to="News" class="topPanelItem textMenu" active-class="activeMenu">News</router-link>
    <div  @click="CreateAcc()" class="topPanelItem textMenu">Support</div>
    <div  @click="CreateAcc()" class="topPanelItem textMenu2">Forum</div>
    <div  @click="downloadmng()" class="topPanelItem textMenu2">Discord</div>
  </div>
```

this download function

```
'
const url = "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/100MB.zip"
ipcRenderer.invoke("downloadmng",url);
```